# Log Out Everywhere not working properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, logout

I used the Stackoverflow 'Log Out Everywhere' from my work machine yesterday.

[image]

When I came back home, and opened stackoverflow.com using a different machine, I was infact logged out, but got the message saying "Welcome back Lazer, you have been logged in, Click to refresh".

I think this might be a bug with the Log Out Everywhere implementation.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73702/what-does-log-out-everywhere-actually-do-and-what-is-it-supposed-to-do

Answer (score 2):

Once you click "Log Out Everywhere" it should stop logging you in automatically; that clears HTML5 Local Storage which contains your network-wide ticket on *that particular browser*.

It's called HTML 5 **Local** Storage for a reason, it is local to the particular browser instance you are running on.

Comment: Is the name of the button not a tad misleading then?  My guess is that it should read something like `Log out of all sites` instead.