# Why do I keep getting logged-in despite logout and revoke?

Tags: bug

I logged out from programmers.SE and have no intention to log back in, yet PSE is very insistent on logging me in whenever I accidentally visit the web site.

I'm using Chrome Sync but I don't think that synchronizes cookies. I'm logging in to other SE sites obviously and I just don't want to login to PSE.

The interesting thing is that I actually revoked access of PSE in my Google Accounts page. It's not listed there yet I keep getting logged in to the web site. This makes me think that there is something wrong with how OAuth is implemented somewhere.

I'm only using Google OAuth to login to SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

That is the [global network auto-login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) feature. As reported in [Allow users to disable auto-login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73699/allow-users-to-disable-auto-login), you can avoid to be automatically logged in on Programmers, if you block https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/login/global, and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/login/global/request.