# How to log out from all Stack Exchange powered sites at once?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log out of all Stack Exchange sites with linked account simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/log-out-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-with-linked-account-simultaneously)

While we have logged in in multiple (say 5) Stack Exchange powered sites, is it possible to log out from all at once?

I myself log in with my Google OpenID. Also, I do not mean something like clearing all cookies. I prefer to do so from within Stack Exchange itself.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA, but I could not see **log out everywhere** button any where. where is it?

Comment: @YasserZamani Read the answer! *The buttons on this page were simplified to just Log Out, which tries to log you out in every way it can. And if you have Stack Exchange credentials the Log Out button will indeed log you out everywhere, network-wide, by redirecting you to a special network-level logout page.*

Comment: @TimYiJiang, do these mean I'll log out from all when I log out from **stackexchange.com** itself rather than others?