# What can a user do if their account is hijacked?

Tags: support, openid

What can a user do if they accidentally leave their Stack Overflow account logged in on a public computer or if their session is hijacked by some other means?  Is there a way to globally log myself* out via my OpenId?

<sub>(*Note: No, I'm not really asking for myself.)</sub>

Comment: I thought the *log me out everywhere* was for every site, and was going to suggest using that from another site in the network; but apparently that only works for only that site... so yeah, ignore this unhelpful comment

Comment: Related: [Pekka's request for a network-wide logout functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality), which seems to imply some lacking degree of doing this, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: @Juan: Actually, knowing that the "log me out everywhere" button still exists behind the logout menu option does help.  I think that's the way to recover from a hijacked session (on a single site, but it logs you out of multiple computers).

Comment: _"Note: No, I'm not really asking for myself."_ <-- so who is asking? The person who hijacked your account?

Comment: @Popular:  I was asking on behalf of another user who I suspect left their account logged in on a public computer.  If someone hijacked my account, they could have a lot more fun than posting this.  ;)

Comment: @Bill, yeah, I figured. It was supposed to be a joke... never mind.

Answer (score 6):

Two things had me confused here.  First, I didn't immediately find the "Log Out Everywhere" button that @Juan mentioned in the comments above.  You can find it by clicking the arrow next to your name at the top of the page and clicking 'logout'.

[image: logout]

Second, Jeff's answer on [Log Out Everywhere not working properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70138/log-out-everywhere-not-working-properly) really led me to believe that the button didn't work as I expected.  Kevin Montrose's answer on [What does “Log Out Everywhere” actually do, and what is it supposed to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73702/what-does-log-out-everywhere-actually-do-and-what-is-it-supposed-to-do/73703#73703) cleared up my remaining confusion.

Comment: Ermmmm ... my confusion has substantially increased after reading [Kevin's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73702/what-does-log-out-everywhere-actually-do-and-what-is-it-supposed-to-do/73703#73703). Does the 2nd part of his answer say 'if I forget to log out from a public computer and use "Log Out Everywhere" on my computer at home, then everyone using that public computer will be automatically re-logged in when surfing to the SOFU/SE site I visited?' If yes, then "Log Out Everywhere" is very much misleading.

Comment: @Hendrik: I'm going to try this when I go home later.  If I'm still logged in at home, I'll have to move this answer up to the question (and back to the "confused" column).

Comment: @Hendrik: I used "Log Out Everywhere" on Meta last night from my home PC and when I came here from work this morning I had to log in again, so it seems to be working.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks! So - does this mean that Kevin's explanation in that 2nd part of his answer is misleading (or maybe plain wrong)?

Comment: @Hendrik: It looks that way.  I at least could not reproduce the behavior Lazer was asking about in the post Kevin linked to.

Comment: @Bill: OK, thanks again. Ah, I just see you already notified Kevin about this - thanks!

Comment: I just saw that the post with Kevin's answer has been deleted in the meantime.

Comment: @Hendrik: Jeff deleted it a few days ago, but I don't know why.